# GNOME shell on 3.16 for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am trying to install gnome-shell 3.16 on ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel version 3.16.

I was only able to upgrade gnome-shell from 3.10 to 3.12.2. After that it is not upgrading to gnome-shell 3.14.

Comment: gnome shell 3.15 and 3.16 appear to have been released for vivid and not trusty. See: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-gnome-packaging/+archive/ubuntu/shell-3.16

Comment: How did you get it to 3.12.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gnome-shell for Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618019/gnome-shell-for-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score -4):

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ricotz/testing

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Please add some formatting and explanation of these commands.

Comment: Why this without any reason? `ppa:ricotz/testing`

Comment: This commands do not work on 14.04. The latest Gnome installed is still 3.12