# Gnome-shell for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04

I recently updated my Ubuntu to 15.04 and now I'm back to Unity shell. The gnome-shell I had became buggy after the update, so I had to revert back. How do I get a Gnome shell (again) without switching to Ubuntu Gnome? I really can't afford to do a reformat right now.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the GNOME Shell 3.14 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

And for GNOME 3.16 or future GNOME versions

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: Does it really look like Unity (for now)? It still has the side dock and all. Also, when I lock my screen, the lock screen still looks like from Ubuntu. Startup lock screen, however, looks like Gnome. Is it still unfinished?

Comment: I also keep getting an error on installing "linux-image-extra-3.19.0-16-generic 3.19.0-16.16"

Comment: This has nothing to do with GNOME. This is a kernel update.

Comment: when installing gnome, choose gdm instead of lightdm when you are asked.. this will give you a more complete look

Comment: As I have said, it still looks like Ubuntu. Is it really like this?

Comment: @ton Which session type you chose when you log in? After selecting a user name, you can specify the type of session in a menu.

Comment: I do not have this setting beside my name (after I lock screen) :(

Comment: Not in the lock screen, log out, select your account, select the session type and log in