# What is the best way to install Gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, desktop-environments

I want to replace unity with Gnome 3.16, but completely confused. Can I install Gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04 (I can't upgrade to 14.10)? Someones says it's impossible but there is some article about that.

What is the best way to do that?
Is it a good idea to install gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04? If not, what about Gnome shell 3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2 ?

Comment: Or you could just install gnome-shell in your current install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gnome-shell for Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618019/gnome-shell-for-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 2):

The latest Gnome 3 you can get on 14.04 is 3.14. In order to do that, you should add staging and testing ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Comment: How safe is this?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off installing the official Gnome flavor, Ubuntu-Gnome. otherwise you will run into issues with the environment because Unity is still underneath it

15.04 will allow you to install 3.16 using the staging ppa already mentioned on this page, 15.10 will come with it pre-installed

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user445034.

You can install Ubuntu-Gnome from https://ubuntugnome.org/

After trying several popular DE's, including Pantheon Unity, Mate, KDE, LxDE, I realised the limitations and/or ugly parts of each. Ubuntu really presents problems changing the DE, this prompted me to try Debian - an excellent OS which handles all the DEs you throw at it without breaking - if not for outdated repositories and all the little workarounds you have to do compared with Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 17 on onwards ships with a Gnome as default DE. But if you're looking for stability on Ubuntu then by all means, use Ubuntu-Gnome (16.04)!