# Why the latest gnome-shell version can not be installed on LTS versions?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

After seeing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622622/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-gnome-3-16-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607674/gnome-shell-on-3-16-for-ubuntu-14-04), and also adding numerous PPA's that have no logical reason to be added, I still can't get to have gnome-shell further than 3.12.2.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME LTS and I am fetching from the GNOME Project PPA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A strict answer to you question "Why?" is:

- Because the maintainers of the repositories decided to not port it to 14.04, as you can see when filtering the versions of Ubuntu ([gnome3](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3?field.series_filter=trusty), [gnome3-staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging?field.series_filter=trusty)).

Probably you also wanted to know whether there is an *easy* way to install it. The answer is no. Why?

- Because apparently it is not compatible with Trusty, too unstable on it and no one have yet it officially ported.
  You can try to compile and install it by following the official [Gnome compile guide](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/source/).

Finally, I just want to point out that your behaviour is contradictory. One uses LTSs because wants stable software (although maybe older). If you want to use new (maybe-not-so-stable-on-Ubuntu) software, you *should* move to the latest Ubuntu version or, even better, change distro and go for a rolling distro.

Installing the latest software (via PPAs or just by installing the debs) on a possibly older LTS release will make it more unstable than the last non-LTS.

Comment: Your last 2 paras are particularly true when applied to an important part of the OS.  They are much less important when applied to something that sits on top of it, where instability won't have wide-reaching effects. (personal example -- being "stuck" on TeX Live 2009 when I was using 12.04LTS; fixed by a clean install in user space but time-consuming)